# Is it logical to loop on model.fit in Keras?

Tags: keras, large-data, batching

Is it logical to do as below in Keras in order not to run out of memory?

```python
for path in ['xaa', 'xab', 'xac', 'xad']:
    x_train, y_train = prepare_data(path)
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=50, epochs=20, shuffle=True)

model.save('model')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is, but prefer `model.train_on_batch` if each iteration is generating a single batch. This eliminates some overhead that comes with `fit`.

You can also try to create a generator and use `model.fit_generator()`:

```py
def dataGenerator(pathes, batch_size):

    while True: #generators for keras must be infinite
        for path in pathes:
            x_train, y_train = prepare_data(path)

            totalSamps = x_train.shape[0]
            batches = totalSamps // batch_size

            if totalSamps % batch_size > 0:
                batches+=1

            for batch in range(batches):
                section = slice(batch*batch_size,(batch+1)*batch_size)
                yield (x_train[section], y_train[section])
```

Create and use:

```
gen = dataGenerator(['xaa', 'xab', 'xac', 'xad'], 50)
model.fit_generator(gen,
                    steps_per_epoch = expectedTotalNumberOfYieldsForOneEpoch
                    epochs = epochs)
```

Comment: Thanks, but what's 'i'?

Comment: LOL... exactly the same mistake as in the other answer :) -- It's `batch`.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest having a look at this [thread](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2708) on Github.

You could indeed consider using `model.fit()`, but it would make the training more stable to do it in such a way:

```python
for epoch in range(20):
    for path in ['xaa', 'xab', 'xac', 'xad']:
        x_train, y_train = prepare_data(path)
        model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=50, epochs=epoch+1, initial_epoch=epoch, shuffle=True)
```

This way you are iterating over all your data once per epoch, and not iterating 20 epochs over part of your data before switching.

As discussed in the thread, another solution would be to develop your own data generator and use it with `model.fit_generator()`.

Comment: Thank you very much, but what do you mean by "i"? Shoudn't it be "epoch"?

Comment: You are right, thanks for spotting my mistake. I corrected my post.

Comment: In this case, when to save the model/weights? After the inner loop finish? Then, load it for the next epoch?